# What's the best way to show the results of different machine learning regression models on a factorial combination of 7 predictors?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I have a dataset with 7 predictors and 1 numerical response. I am modelling them with different ML regression models (so far: SVM, tree, Gaussian Process, Ensemble and neural networks) in MATLAB.

To further test the different combinations of the predictors, I tested every possibility of a combination of the predictors.

Now I am wondering what would be an efficient way to summarize the results that I have, I am definitely thinking about using just a normal table displaying R² and RMSE, but I would be open to other suggestions.

Thanks in advance!